# Haskell count positive and negative numbers separately in a list

Tags: haskell

I can count number of positive occurrence with this:

```
count :: [Int] -> Int
count xs = length [ x | x <- xs, x > 0]
```

However, I can't make it work to count both positive and negative numbers.

For the input `[1,2,3, -1,-2]` I want `(3,2)` as an output. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The input is some list of arbitrarily large (but finite) length, and the output is accumulated into a compact value of type (Int,Int). So it is a *folding* operation. See doc of library function [`foldl'`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldl-39-) . For a more detailed explanation, see the relevant LYAH chapter at learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#folds

Comment: Surely you can see a way to implement this that doesn't require anything you don't already have, but just counts the positive and negative numbers separately and gives back both results? Start with that. The solution with a single `fold'` is more efficient, but it's unlikely to matter in practice.

Comment: Cute but obfuscated: `map length . group . sort . map (>0)` (don't do this)

Answer (score 0):

You can work with a "fold". Here you pass a 2-tuple as "accumulator" and you increment one of the two, depending on whether the item is positive or negative.

This thus looks like:

```
import Data.Foldable(foldl')

count_pn :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> (Int, Int)
count_pn = foldl' f (0, 0)
  where f (np, nn) x
          | … = …
          | otherwise = …
```

Here you need to still implement the `f` function. Here `(np, nn)` is the 2-tuple with the amount of positive and negative items counted so far, and `x` the element we want to count next.